# Statistics impact on db2 optimizer plan

Tags: optimization, db2, statistics

Has the creation of statistics any impact on the estimated costs and the optimizer plan given by db2 optimizer. Or will (in the best case) only the execution time of a query change?

I ran something like this. Is this right/useful?

```
RUNSTATS ON TABLE DB2INST1.ARTISTS WITH DISTRIBUTION DEFAULT NUM_FREQVALUES 50 NUM_QUANTILES 5 AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE DB2INST1.ARTISTS ON KEY COLUMNS;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE DB2INST1.ARTIST ON COLUMNS((COUNTRY,ARTIST_NAME),(ID,ARTIST_NAME),(CONTACT_MAIL,CONTACT_PHONE),(WEBSITE,TWITTER,SOUNDCLOUD,FACEBOOK));
```

Two queries I ran on this database were:

```
SELECT * FROM ARTISTS WHERE WEBSITE IS NOT NULL AND TWITTER IS NOT NULL AND SOUNDCLOUD IS NOT NULL AND FACEBOOK IS NOT NULL
SELECT YEAR, FORMAT, count(*) AS ANZAHL, sum(TRACK_LENGTH) AS GESAMTLAENGE_sec FROM RELEASES JOIN TRACKS ON RELEASES.ID = TRACKS.RELEASE_ID GROUP BY YEAR, FORMAT ORDER BY YEAR DESC
```

The execution time of both queries was better than before running runstats. But the estimated cost and the optimizer plan given by db2expln were exactly the same.

db2expln command:

```
db2expln -q [one of the queries above] -t -g -d $dbname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only agree in what Michael said, statistics is very important for any cost-based optimizer (like db2's and most (all?) modern RDBMs). In addition to that I suggest that you have a look at `db2exfmt`. It uses a slightly different method to determine the plan, and IMO provides much nicer output. There are several ways to populate the explain tables, two examples are:

```
#> db2 "explain plan for SELECT * FROM ARTISTS WHERE WEBSITE IS NOT NULL AND TWITTER IS NOT NULL AND SOUNDCLOUD IS NOT NULL AND FACEBOOK IS NOT NULL"
```

or

```
#> db2 set current explain mode explain
#> db2 "SELECT * FROM ARTISTS WHERE WEBSITE IS NOT NULL AND TWITTER IS NOT NULL AND SOUNDCLOUD IS NOT NULL AND FACEBOOK IS NOT NULL"
#> db2 set current explain mode no
```

Now you can use `db2exfmt` to present the result. You can choose what plan to present in a variate of ways, but I usually just choose the last plan (-1):

```
#> db2exfmt -d <database> -g -1 -o query.exfmt  
#> less -S query.exfmt
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly yes - statistics are very important inputs for the optimizer!
This is what statistics are for.
Besides that configuation, data model (objects) etc. have an effect as well.
YOu can influence the optimization class to determine which optimizer techniques will be considered by the SQL Query Compiler and the DB2 cost based optimizer which is part of that.

Comment: Okay. Am I right that level 5 uses statistics? And if yes. Why do I see no difference in the optimizer plan?

Comment: All level use statistics - the is a difference in the level of detail they use (like distribution stats) - they differ in optimization techniques applied